# Can't find installed kernel and make older kernel as default kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2, kernel-modules

I use Linux 5.4.0 LTS in Ubuntu. Now I installed a new kernel Linux 5.6.7 stable using these commands

```
sudo make modules_install
sudo make install
```

Now my default kernel is Linux 5.6.7. After installing the kernel I couldn't find the kernel in directory. It does not show in terminal too. When run the command,

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

The new kernel was not in the list.

```
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic               5.4.0-26.30                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                        5.4.0.26.32                                amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

These header installed where C header installed. Can I make Linux 5.6.7 an image like Linux 5.4.0 and bring it in `/usr/src/kernels`?

Linux 5.6.7 is now default kernel for booting. How can I make Linux 5.4.0 as my default kernel for booting?

As Linux 5.6.7 is not in dpkg list the command `sudo apt remove linux-kernel`. How can I remove if I want to remove it?

Comment: Did you compile and install the new kernel from source? If so, your package manager is likely completely unaware of it. For the PM to be aware, you would need to build it into a new .deb package and install with the PM.